# duplicated useres detection and deletion from UAAdb

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

I have experienced an issue that User exists twice with the same user name in the uaa db. Is there any script that does detection of ducplicated users and deletetion?

What is the best way you would suggest for the detection and deletion?

Answer (score 0):

UAA does not allow you add the same user twice.

You can try the following..

> $ uaac target
>
> $ uaac token client get admin -s
>
> $ uaac users | grep -i username
>
> $ uaac clients | grep -i username

This will give you the list of UAA users and clients. 
Give it a try.